# ui bootstrap pagination not working inside a ng-if tag

Tags: angularjs, twitter-bootstrap, angular-ui-bootstrap

I try to hide the pagination div when there is nothing to show. So I write this:

```
<div ng-if="totalItems!=0">
     <pagination
          boundary-links="true"
          total-items="totalItems"
          ng-model="currentPage"
          ng-change="pageChanged()"
          class="pagination"                                 
          items-per-page="itemsPerPage"
          max-size="7">
     </pagination>
</div>
```

But when clicking, only the `pageChanged()` function is triggered, the `currentPage` won't change. Removing the ng-if div outsite solves this.
Is there a way to work around?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`ng-if` creates a new scope like `ng-repeat`, so the `currentPage` is inside the child scope and not accessible on main scope.

There are a couple ways that you can try to resolve it:

1. use `ng-show` instead of `ng-if`
2. declare `$scope.currentPage = 1` early in your main controller (not sure if this will work)
3. use `ng-model="$parent.currentPage"` instead
4. use dot notation: declare $scope.something in controller then use `ng-model="something.currentPage"`

Comment: #5 best option in my mind (assuming ng-if stays). Allows for inheritance that primitives don't have

Comment: You meant #4, #1 was inserted accedentally so I have removed it ;p